# Python Generate a random Maxwell distribution from a normal distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, scipy

I have a set of data that follows a normal distribution in which I can fit the histogram and obtain the mean and sigma.

For the sake of example, I will approximate it by generating a random normal distribution as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import maxwell
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from IPython import embed # put embed() where you want to stop
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

    data = random.gauss(307, 16)
    N, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, bins=40, density=True, alpha=0.5, histtype='bar', ec='black')
    mu, std = norm.fit(data)
    xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
    x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
    p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
    plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2, label= r'$\mu$ = '+'{:0.1f}'.format(mu)+r' $\pm$ '+'{:0.1f}'.format(std))
```

What I would like to do next is to generate a Maxwell distribution from this "normal" distribution and be able to fit

I have read [scipy.stats.maxwell](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html) webpage and several other related questions but was not able to generate such a distribution from "a gauss distribution" and fit it. Any help would much appreciate it.

Comment: Could you add all the relevant `import` statements required to run your code?  We can probably make pretty good guesses about what they are, but we shouldn't have to. :)

Comment: *"... but was not able to generate such a distribution from "a gauss distribution" and fit it. "* What, exactly, did you try, and what went wrong?  Did you get errors, or just unexpected results?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have added the imported packages. I have tried doing ax.plot(data, maxwell.pdf(data),'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='maxwell pdf')
and ax.plot(data, maxwell.pdf(x),'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='maxwell pdf') which x is supposed to be the gauss output. In the first case, it did not fit at all and in the second case, It gave me an error. Still not sure what is the right way!

Comment: `random.gauss(307, 16)` generates *one* sample.  I don't see the point of fitting a normal distribution (or a Maxwell distribution) to a single point.  `norm.fit(data)` will return exactly that point as the mean (i.e. the location) and 0 as the standard deviaiton (i.e. the scale). Is that really the complete code that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Well, knowing that each Maxwell is distribution of the absolute value of the molecule velocity, where each component is normally distributed, you could make sampling like code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import maxwell

def maxw(size = None):
    """Generates size samples of maxwell"""
    vx = np.random.normal(size=size)
    vy = np.random.normal(size=size)
    vz = np.random.normal(size=size)
    return np.sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy + vz*vz)

mdata = maxw(100000)
h, bins = np.histogram(mdata, bins = 101, range=(0.0, 10.0))

x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, 100)
rv = maxwell()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.hist(mdata, bins = bins, density=True)
ax.plot(x, rv.pdf(x), 'k-', lw=2, label='Maxwell pdf')
plt.title("Maxwell")
plt.show()
```

And here is the picture with sampling and Maxwell PDF overlapped

[image]