# Python RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide return n/db/n.sum(), bin_edges

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, statistics

My goal is to generate a random 2-D normal distribution with the desired mean and sigma and be able to fit that with the Maxwellian distribution. I have modified a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717317/python-generate-a-random-maxwell-distribution-from-a-normal-distribution) in StackOverflow but I keep getting the error in the title. I have tried to play with bin size but apparently, if the bins do not start from 0, it keeps giving me that error:

```
from scipy.stats import maxwell
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker     


def maxw(size = None):
    """Generates size samples of maxwell"""
    mu, sigma = 307, 16
    vx = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=size)
    vy = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=size)
    vz = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=size)
    return np.sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy + vz*vz)

mdata = maxw(100000)
h, bins = np.histogram(mdata, bins = 101, range=(290.0, 320.0))
x = np.linspace(290.0, 320.0, 100)
rv = maxwell()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.hist(mdata, bins = bins, density=True, color='blue', alpha=0.7, histtype='bar', ec='black')
ax.plot(x, rv.pdf(x), 'k-', lw=2, label='Maxwell pdf')
plt.title("Maxwell")
plt.show()
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're generating a histogram in a region where there is no data:

The line

```py
>>> h, bins = np.histogram(mdata, bins = 101, range=(290.0, 320.0))
```

returns a histogram array which is all zeros:

```py
>>> h
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

This is because the mean of the quadrature sum of distributions (the output of your `maxw` function) is not the mean of each distribution in the sum.  It is the quadrature sum of the means (i.e. `np.sqrt(3*307^2) ~ 530`), so you were making a histogram of zero values.

You can fix this either by changing the range of the `np.histogram` function, or just removing the range altogether, and then changing your `x` array to be something like

```py
>>> x = np.linspace(min(mdata), max(mdata), 100)
```

Alternatively, you can just let matplotlib's own histogram function take care of everything:

```py
>>> plt.hist(mdata, bins=100)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes Indeed when I leave it to matplotlib it does the job. However I don't get why it is not able to fit the histogram when I give a mean and sigma, where as if I use the random sampling with the standard values vx = np.random.normal (I believe in that case mean is zero and std is 1) it will create a distribution (for 3-D case) that can be fitted with maxwellian!